# How can I limit the amount of text in a DIV that I periodically add messages to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a web based program that receives one line text messages periodically from the server (with Node.js and socket.io) that I append to a scrolling DIV.  The messages are simple text; for example, "Input switch failed".

```
socket.on('statusMessage', function (newMessage) {
  $('#statusMessageDiv').append(newMessage + "<br>");
});
```

How can I remove older messages when new ones come in, so I can limit the messages displayed to the last 200 or so?

Comment: Give each in a span, counts the spans and remvoe the leading ones

Comment: Is the new message just simply text? or does it have some HTML markup in it? You could count the <br> tags and remove when there are 200 or more.

Comment: The messages are just simple text, for example "switch 1 activated".

Comment: you don't need to wrap it with an element. a text node is a valid node.  but either way you can use `filter()`. see below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the messages in an element, count the elements, and if more than 200, remove the last appended (the first one) :

```
socket.on('statusMessage', function (data) {
    $('<p />', {text : newMessage}).appendTo('#statusMessageDiv');

    if ( $('p', '#statusMessageDiv').length > 200 )
        $('p', '#statusMessageDiv').first().remove();
});
```

Comment: `<p></p><br>`, Oh, my eyes!

Comment: @Alexander - nothing wrong with that, but with paragraphs the breaks are'nt really needed!

Comment: That is, if you meant syntactically speaking but not semantically speaking ;)

Comment: @Alexander - are you saying you can't have a break inside a div if it contains paragraphs ?

Comment: Eh? Of course not. I think you didn't understand my initial expression anyways ;)

Comment: You should probably cache your `$("p", "#statusMessageDiv")`

Answer (score 2):

What about

`$("#statusMessageDiv span:gt(200)").remove()` (Might be 199 as zero based!)

Assuming statusMessageDiv contains `<span>` tags. This assumed that the oldest ones are at the bottom of the pile.

Example fiddle of basic principle: http://jsfiddle.net/9ZKXY/

Edit: Updated fiddle with removing first/last items: http://jsfiddle.net/9ZKXY/1/

Comment: This is a great idea, but they need to remove the oldest - which are at the beginning, not the end. So in your fiddle, they should remove 1, 2 and 3

Comment: Ahh ok, well, in my (probably) simple head, inverting by using `lt` should do the trick, then? I added an edit.

Comment: You're right, but to get that to work dynamically takes more work, because it depends on the length of items in the element. For example, to always only allow 200, you wouldn't use `:lt(200)` (or 199)

Answer (score 1):

Or you could have a javascript array as a datastructure containing the string values of the messages. Do an ajax call to get the new messages with a JSON result as an array of the new messages. Splice the datastructure array with the count of the JSON result array to remove the needed items. Then add the new items to the datastructure array. And then using a library like KnockoutJS or AngularJS bind your Div to the datastructure. That way when you add and remove new items to the datastructure, your rendering div will show accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep your existing structure then what you are trying to remove by is the first line with each additional line.  The "first line" is made up of two nodes -- a text node and br node.  So we can filter those out as we append the newMessage

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gillyspy/YSENt/)

```
socket.on('statusMessage', function (newMessage) {    
    var i = 0;        
    $('#statusMessages').append(newMessage + "<br/>")
    .contents()
    .filter(function () {
        i++;
        return i <= 2 ? this : false; // 2 because one text node and one br node
    })
    .remove();
}); // end on statusMessage
```